# Is it possible to compile a data file into the final binary?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a [data-file](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-data-files) in one of my projects and when I want to distribute just the compiled binary the data file is not included and I get following error:

```
copyFile:atomicCopyFileContents:withReplacementFile:copyFileToHandle:openBinaryFile: 
does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I know I could embed the file with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed, but I feel like this should already by provided by cabal / stack.
Is there a flag for cabal or stack to automatically include the file into the binary?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Template Haskell? It's clearly the right tool for stuff like this.

Comment: I meant to say that it shouldn't be necessary. Went with the template solution for the time being: https://github.com/ad-si/TaskLite/commit/c74f46a8100dc9ab2edddc62b089a18cf0b9a6d7

Comment: There's also "data-embed" https://github.com/valderman/data-embed https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-embed which works by modifying your executable using the "embedtool" program.

Comment: Thanks @danidiaz for the pointer. That's more like what I envisioned. I guess this could also be used to implement the functionality in cabal / stack…